# TensorRT 5 UFFParser error about kernel weights

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, nvidia, tensorrt

I'm trying to convert then run inference with a Tensorflow model.

I generate a Tensorflow model with tf.keras:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(224,224,3), name='image'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name='output'))
```

i train the model then i convert the file saving a .pb tensorflow frozen graph file, converted to UFF with:

```
uff_model = uff.from_tensorflow_frozen_model(
frozen_file="model/tensorflow/simplemodel.pb",
output_nodes=["output/Softmax"],
output_filename="model/tensorrt/simplemodel.uff")
```

When i parse the model with:

```
TRT_LOGGER = trt.Logger(trt.Logger.INFO)
builder = trt.Builder(TRT_LOGGER)
network = builder.create_network()
parser = trt.UffParser()
parser.register_input("image_input", (1, 224, 224, 3))
parser.register_output("output/SoftMax")
parser.parse("model/tensorrt/simplemodel.uff", network)
```

i got this error:

```
[TensorRT] INFO: UFFParser: parsing image_input
[TensorRT] INFO: UFFParser: parsing image/kernel
[TensorRT] INFO: UFFParser: parsing image/Conv2D
[TensorRT] INFO: UFFParser: parsing image/bias
[TensorRT] INFO: UFFParser: parsing image/BiasAdd
[TensorRT] ERROR: image/Conv2D: kernel weights has count 1728 but 129024 was expected
[TensorRT] ERROR: UFFParser: Parser error: image/BiasAdd: The input to the Scale Layer is required to have a minimum of 3 dimensions.
```

Why the error about kernel weights count ? I set the input shape with correct size (224,244,3...), this is my model:

---

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
image (Conv2D)               (None, 222, 222, 64)      1792
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 220, 220, 32)      18464
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 1548800)           0
_________________________________________________________________
output (Dense)               (None, 6)                 9292806
=================================================================
Total params: 9,313,062
Trainable params: 9,313,062
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Thanks,

Igor

Comment: Can it possible to check input shape and input name of uff model? I think problem is somewhere in input.

Comment: The uff model contains:  nodes {
    id: "image_input"
    operation: "Input"
    fields {
      key: "dtype"
      value {
        dtype: DT_FLOAT32
      }
    }
    fields {
      key: "shape"
      value {
        i_list {
          val: -1
          val: 224
          val: 224
          val: 3
        }
      }
    }
  }

Answer (score 1):

Tensorrt uses NCHW format. Hence

```
parser.register_input("image_input", (1, 224, 224, 3))
```

should have been

```
parser.register_input("image_input", (1, 3, 224, 224))
```

In your case it assumed 224 to be the number of channels in the input. Hence the number of weights parameters would be 224*64*3*3 = 129204 (input_channels*output_channels*kernel_height*kernel*width)